# Is "down at the bar" an adjective phrase or adverb phrase?

Tags: adjectives, phrase-structure, adverbs, phrases

There are three parts of speeches attributed to "down" in the dictionary: adjective, adverb and verb.

I understand , that *at the bar* is a sub phrase and a prepositional phrase.
I don't know the rules of how each type of phrase is allowed to be built and I don't know where to look those rules up. Maybe a prepositional phrase can follow both an adverb and an adjective or maybe only one of them. Maybe some phrases are ambient and can be both types , but I am just guessing.

The whole sentence, wherein I found the phrase is:

> Plenty of seats down at the bar

Comment: "down" can also be a preposition: "the kids ran *down* the street", "the camera fell *down* the hill"

Comment: That's interesting, would "from down the hill" be a prepositional phrase which has another prepositional phrase for a sub phrase?

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred Yes, "Down at the bar" is a preposition phrase headed by the prep "down" which has the further PP "at the bar" as its complement. The larger PP is either a modifier of the NP "seats", or a locative adjunct depending on its function in the sentence.